# remove msvc dlls dependency to run qt application

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, qt, visual-c++

How to remove msvc dlls (example: msvcr100.dll) dependency to run qt appliation?
I've developed a qt application which runs just fine in dveloper machine but unable to run on any other machine gives error message "program can't start because MSVCR100.dll is missing from your computer". I can solve this error by copying that file in the application folder but I dont want to copy, instead I want to link statically or some other way to remove that dependency.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you got the answer you were looking for?

Comment: yes only from the  two answers from this forum  .. http://blog.diplix.de/2011/08/23/qt-with-visual-studio-2010-and-static-linking/ shows of how statically linking might solve .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are probably trying to run an application on a machine which has a different Visual Studio (MSVC) version installed than the version that was used for building your application itself.

Generally, the correct solution is to install the corresponding Visual Studio redistributable package on the target machine. It is not a "workaround" or "hack" because if you wish to use an application built with different runtime libraries, etc, then it is expected. Here you can read a bit more about it:

[Redistributing Visual C++ Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235299.aspx)

Yes, it is a bit unfortunate, and apparently MS has not managed to make it the most ideal, but after all, it is simple enough to circumvent. Note that the target machine would not only have issues with your application, but in general with any distributed in a similar fashion.

The other way to solve the issue is to build the application with the same environment that is installed on the target machine, but this can easily go haywire if you need to supply the application to several machines with versatile setup. Now, I would say this is the "hackish" approach.

You will need to grab the redistributable for this particular problem from here:

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5555)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=14632)

Even if you went down for statically hacking this around somehow, you would need to deal with nasty consequences when using your application with DLLs and static libraries, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't link statically to Visual Studio Redistributable. Any application built with Visual Studio Compiler needs the corresponding msvcXXX.dll to run. Installers containing all dll for each specific version of MSVC are available here: http://search.microsoft.com/en-us/DownloadResults.aspx?q=redistributable

If you want avoid errors for your users when you distribute your application, you have some solution. A commonly used is to install the right redistributable package before installing your application on the user machine. Often used tools (NSIS, Inno Setup, etc.) have options to run other executable in the process. And each Microsoft redist package can be run silently (without any window display to user).

Note: This problem is absolutely not related to qt. It comes directly from the compiler you choose.