# Qt 5.4 static build produces "unresolved external symbol" link error in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, linker, static-linking

I want to use a static build of Qt 5.4. Since there is no precompiled static build available, you have to build one from the Qt source code yourself.

My environment is the following:

- Windows 7 x64
- Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 4
- Qt5 Visual Studio Add-in 1.2.4
- ActivePerl / ActivePython installed (required to build Qt source)

My procedure was the following (cf. Qt Documentation > Qt 5.4 > Qt for Windows - Building from Source):

- Download qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.0.zip
- Extract to a temp folder
- Open a command prompt as described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html#step-3-set-the-environment-variables) (basically, this is similar to open a "Visual Studio Command Prompt" and adding some paths to the path variable)
- Run configure with the following command

  ```
  configure -c++11 -mp -release -static -nomake tests -nomake examples -prefix D:\Qt\qt-5.4.0-x86-msvc2013-compact-static -platform win32-msvc2013 -opengl desktop -no-icu -skip webkit
  ```
- Run `nmake` and `nmake install`

All this run through without errors.

Then in Visual Studio, I changed the Qt version of an existing Qt project to `D:\Qt\qt-5.4.0-x86-msvc2013-compact-static` as this was the output folder of the above procedure.

However, now I get tons of unresolved symbol errors of the following kind (build configuration "release"):

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp__glBindTexture@8". Qt5Gui.lib(qopenglfunctions.obj)
...
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_hb_blob_create".    Qt5Gui.lib(qharfbuzzng.obj)
...
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_hb_face_create_for_tables". Qt5Gui.lib(qharfbuzzng.obj)
....
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_WSAAsyncSelect@16". Qt5Core.lib(qeventdispatcher_win.obj)
```

A shared library / dynamic linking build with similar options (`-platform win32-msvc2013 -opengl desktop -no-icu -skip webkit`) works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update Jan 6th:**

1) As already mentioned in the comments, this *may* be a bug in Qt, so I created a bug report (QTBUG-43636), and later I found a probably related bug (QTBUG-38913). *(Sorry, I can post no more than 2 links)*

2) I found out (thanks to karlphillip) that you can reduce the number of error messages if you add some libraries to your additional dependencies in Visual Studio

- `Ws2_32.lib` resolves one error message (out of 103)
- `opengl32.lib` resolves 47 error messages

This means there are now "only" [55 error messages left](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/secure/attachment/45690/errorlist_new.txt). Maybe there are still more libraries missing?

Comment: 1) Smells like a bug in Qt. Have you considered [reporting it](http://bugreports.qt-project.org/)? 2) Not being a Windows prouser myself: are you sure that now it's 100% supported to provide a prefix path / to run make install?

Comment: [Have you seen this?](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/10990/#61132)

Comment: It's written on the website that you can use prefix and nmake install http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html
Adding imm32.lib winmm.lib Ws2_32.lib does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Update: To be more precise, adding Ws2_32.lib actually resolves one of the 103 errors. ("_WSAAsyncSelect@16" in qeventdispatcher_win.obj) The other 102 are still present when I add those three libs.
Update 2: Now there is also a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-43636).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**I found the solution:**

You have to add the following libraries to your additional dependencies in Visual Studio:

`Ws2_32.lib
opengl32.lib
qtharfbuzzng.lib`

Then, my project finally compiled.

**However, that is not the end of the story:**

Although successfully compiled, my application showed the following error message on startup:

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows".

To solve this, you have to add even more libraries to your additional dependencies:

`imm32.lib
winmm.lib
Qt5PlatformSupport.lib
qwindows.lib`

...and the following to your additional library directories:

`$(QTDIR)\plugins\platforms`

...and the following to your source code:

```
#include <QtPlugin>
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QWindowsIntegrationPlugin)
```

Done! Finally, I was able to link against static Qt libraries.

**It was worth the effort:**

The cold startup time of my application improved dramatically from about 10 seconds to less than 1 second. And instead of 14 MB DLL-files I only have to deploy a single 8 MB EXE-file.

Comment: Great tutorial, thanks. I only add that when creating static libraries a change have to be made within ${QtDir}\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013\qmake.conf. Details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6494649/1648045).

Comment: @mr.pohl: Yes, if you want to link against static Visual Studio runtime libraries, you have to make these changes. But that's not mandatory, since you can just ask the end user to install the appropriate Visual C++ Redistributable Package. ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042764/remove-msvc-dlls-dependency-to-run-qt-application)). Also, it must be mentioned that Qt advises not to link against static Visual Studio runtime. ([see here](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/why_does_a_statically_built_qt_use_the_dynamic_visual_studio_runtime_librar))

Comment: Thx,but where can find those dependencies?